# Решил изучить css анимацию. Но не понимаю как сделать корректный mouse out

Tags: css3

Вроде вот он нужный результат, но анимация второго объекта стартует сразу после загрузки страницы, а это не то, что требуется. Эффект должен быть идентичен первому объекту. Навёл - санимировал, убрал мышь с объекта - санимировал в обратном порядке.
Одним словом, творческий затык.
Пример здесь:

```css
#area {
          width: 162px;
          height: 162px;
}

.rotate {
          transition: all 0.5s linear;
          border: solid 5px #ff0000;
          width: 150px;
          height: 150px;
          display: block;
          opacity: 0.2;
}
 
.rotate:hover {


          transform: rotate(180deg);
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          opacity: 1;
          
}


#rotate_01
{
 width:340px; height:262px;
  border: solid 5px #FF0000;
 opacity:0.2;
 /*transition: linear 1s;*/
  /*transition: all 1s linear;*/
  animation: morph_mouse_out 1s linear;
  

}


#rotate_01:hover {
 opacity:1.0;
 animation: morph 1s linear;
 /*width: 240px; height: 200px;*/ /*прописал в саму анимацию, иначе если оттуда убрать, то прыгать начинает*/
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* без этого кода div переворачиваться! */
          
}

@keyframes morph {
    0%   {transform: rotate(0deg); opacity:0.2; width:340px; height:262px; }
    25%  {}
    50%  {transform: rotate(90deg); opacity:0.5;}
    75%  {}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg); opacity:1.0; width: 240px; height: 200px;}
}

@keyframes morph_mouse_out {
    0%   {transform: rotate(180deg); opacity:1.0; width: 240px; height: 200px;}
    25%  {}
    50%  {transform: rotate(90deg); opacity:0.5;}
    75%  {}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg); opacity:0.2; width:340px; height:262px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <div class="rotate">
  Здесь просто и понятно.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rotate_01">
А вот здесь, как сделать, чтобы при запуске\обновлении страницы этот div не анимировал?
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#area {
          width: 162px;
          height: 162px;
}

.rotate {
          transition: all 0.5s linear;
          border: solid 5px #ff0000;
          width: 150px;
          height: 150px;
          display: block;
          opacity: 0.2;
}
 
.rotate:hover {


          transform: rotate(180deg);
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
          opacity: 1;
          
}


#rotate_01
{
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
 width:340px; height:262px;
  border: solid 5px #FF0000;
 opacity:0.2;
 /*transition: linear 1s;*/
  /*transition: all 1s linear;*/
 
  

}


#rotate_01:hover {
 opacity:1.0;
 animation: morph 1s linear;
 /*width: 240px; height: 200px;*/ /*прописал в саму анимацию, иначе если оттуда убрать, то прыгать начинает*/
transform: rotate(180deg);
}

@keyframes morph {
    0%   {transform: rotate(0deg); opacity:0.2; width:340px; height:262px; }
    25%  {}
    50%  {transform: rotate(90deg); opacity:0.5;}
    75%  {}
    100% {transform: rotate(180deg); opacity:1.0; width: 240px; height: 200px;}
}

@keyframes morph_mouse_out {
    0%   {transform: rotate(180deg); opacity:1.0; width: 240px; height: 200px;}
    25%  {}
    50%  {transform: rotate(90deg); opacity:0.5;}
    75%  {}
    100% {transform: rotate(0deg); opacity:0.2; width:340px; height:262px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <div class="rotate">
  Здесь просто и понятно.
  </div>
</div>

<div id="rotate_01">
А вот здесь, как сделать, чтобы при запуске\обновлении страницы этот div не анимировал?
</div>
```

Уберите вот эту строчку   `animation: morph_mouse_out 1s linear;`
от сюда

```
#rotate_01
{
    width:340px; height:262px;
  border: solid 5px #FF0000;
    opacity:0.2;
    /*transition: linear 1s;*/
  /*transition: all 1s linear;*/
}
```

Comment: Он у вас при завершении анимации (при hover) спрыгивает на начальный размер.

Comment: добавил `width: 240px; height: 200px;` к hover и всё заработало прекрасно! Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @I_CaR Пожалуйста

Comment: есть еще такое свойство как animation-fill-mode, которое управляет тем перематывать анимацию в начало или нет по окончании. и добавление в animation фразы reverse, экономит прописывание множество байтов - это к слову о лишнем зеркальном @keyframe